# Largest number of successful consecutive launches by rocket model?

Tags: launch-vehicle, statistics

Which orbital rocket model has the largest number of successful consecutive missions?
Active and inactive models.

Falcon 9 just reached [77](https://twitter.com/nextspaceflight/status/1351900535738142721).

Delta II reached [100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_II).

Is there any other model with a better performance?

I am asking for the first three places.

Delta II might be the first but I am interested in number 2 and 3 too.

Rockets like Long March 3B and Long March 3C are considered the same model.

Mission is not the same as launch. The Falcon 9 - Amos 6 mission exploded before flight.

If you count missions, then Falcon 9 has 77 consecutive successful missions.

If you strictly count only launches, then Falcon 9 has 86 consecutive successful launches.

Yet the majority of people mean missions when they say launches. Because the Amos 6 mission exploded before launch but still it was a planned launch which obviously failed. And I go with that

Comment: What research have you done towards answering this question?

Comment: It looks like there are 112 consecutive successful Soyuz-U launches between 1990 Jul 11 and 1996 May  5, can anyone confirm?

Comment: Random guy on Twitter said that, the Delta II is confirmed in Wikipedia

Comment: @JoeJobs There's a list of [all Falcon 9 launches on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Falcon_9_and_Falcon_Heavy_launches), and if you count all the consecutive successful missions (just subtract the numbers and add 1), and it is indeed 77. [Here's a list of all Soyuz missions,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Soyuz_missions) and the largest number of successful consecutive launches is 90.

Comment: Also, are you only including in-flight failures or both in-flight and pre-flight? Some rockets fail during flight, and some fail on the launch pad. If you're only including in-flight failures, then Falcon 9 has 86 successful consecutive launches. (SpaceX doesn't count pre-flight failures as an attempt).

Comment: I cant find any Soyuz U in that list. Can you find any failure between launches 1990 Jul 11 and 1996 May 5?

Comment: +1 Are you counting identical launch vehicles or ones with major upgrades as still being "roughly similar"?. The former would distinguish missions by upper stage (Soyuz, Long March) and by different first stage boosters (Delta II, Long March) and also divide Falcon 9 into at least two substantially different vehicles from a risk perspective given the extent of upgrades (engines upgrade, octaweb, stage capacity etc etc).  NB good that you've observed Missions/Flights distinction.

Comment: Thank you for the added sources here and in your newer question, *looks great!*

Comment: @Puffin - No, I do not count them different. Long March 3B and 3C are both considered LM 3 (by me). All Falcon 9 are same model. Basically "Family Model version" is equal with "Family Model"

Comment: Are you limiting this to rockets capable of putting payloads into orbit?  (As compared, e.g., to short-range military missiles, whose successful flight completion rate is probably over 99%)

Comment: Dang I forgot to mention orbital. Fixed now

Comment: Are you interested in a) "claimed successful" or b) plausibly verifiable due to the target orbit being publicised before hand? The latter criteria would mess up the claims of all the major launch vehicles that have taken part in black programmes or un-announced military launches.  Putting it another way, under-performances of upper stages certainly do occur, but they are only announced as such on missions with public disclosure. Statistically it doesn't seem valid that secret missions should be immune.

Comment: Any of them - both cases are good